# After upgrade from angular5 to angular 7, How to fix cannot find the webpack harmony-module error?

Tags: angular

I upgraded from angular 5 to angular 7 and now when i try to build my project it throws an Error: Cannot find module './node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js'

I have the module but it can't find it somehow and throws an error, I've tried deleting node_modules and npm install but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you added this script in your `angular.json` file ?

Comment: No should I add webpack or just harmony-module and how can I do that?

Comment: When i build the project 
[405] external "./node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js" 42 bytes {0} [built] 
this passes and at the end it throws an error but the harmony-module is there

Comment: try to force-reinstall harmony: `npm i harmony`

Comment: I'd add this line in `angular.json` > `projects` > ... > `script` array : `"node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js`

Comment: I added that to the angular.json file but it still crashes with the same error